# Django Jquery get selected value display undefined

Tags: python, jquery, django

Hi I'm having issue with passing data to jquery. In my select I have added onchange method and it calls getProductData and pass this select element. In getProductData I get the element and display the selected value. I tried using few methods but the output of alert is [object Object] or undefined.

I'm not using $('#select_id').on('change') because it in a dynamic row and each id for tr, select and input are the same. For a better understanding, please view this
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iF4R.png)

**forms.py**

```
    PD_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        label = "Product Name",
        queryset = Product.objects.only('name').order_by('id'),
        to_field_name = 'id',
        empty_label = "",
        widget = forms.Select(
            attrs = {
                'class': 'form-control',
                'onblur': """form_validation({
                    'element' : this,
                    })""",
                'onchange': """getProductData({
                    'element' : this,
                    })"""
                }
            )
        )
```

**html**

```
<td>{{ Productform.PD_name }}</td>
```

**JQuery**

```
function getProductData(element) {
        alert(element.value);
}
```

Comment: you can access it from ``element.target.value`` instead of ``element.value`` and it should be ``{'onchange' : "getProductData(event);"}`` inside your **forms.py**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Forms:**

```
{'onchange' : "getProductData(this.value);"}
```

**JS:**

```
getProductData(value) {
    console.log(value)
}
```